# I need help designing a speed control dc motor circuit

Tags: motor, dc, control, speed

We were asked to design a motor speed control circuit using the following components:

`15V source -> potentiometer -> LPF -> OpAmp -> ADC -> DAC -> OpAmp -> Motor Driver -> 3V DC Motor` (because of its low cost)

I am going to wire this on a breadboard.

[image: Version 2.(With changes as suggested by JIm Dearden]

**1.** First things first, I have a 15 and -15 Source (VCC, VEE)

**1.1** (Update) I have two 20k resistors before the pot so I would have finer control over the motor (-3V to +3V)

**2.** A low pass filter with a cut off frequency of 100Hz (My prof suggests that we use this value just to clear unwanted signals)

**3.** An OpAmp with unity gain because I need something to drive the transistors from the high-impedance output of the pot.

**4.** A push-pull amp configuration that consists of the NPN and PNP transistors so that I can make my motor spin either way (i.e., a motor driver).

So my questions are:

1. **Are my resistor/capacitor values practical?**
2. **How do I implement the ADC -> DAC part?**
3. **Do I need to place a resistor before the pot so that it won't burn out due
   to high voltage?**

Notes:

- No PWM.
- The motor driver circuit can also be an H-Bridge circuit or IC but I think that would be more expensive.

I also need some suggestions on how to improve the circuit.

Comment: "Do I need to place a resistor before the pot so that it won't burn out due to high voltage?" - Maybe. It is 10K and you have 30 volts across it. Power is V^2/R so it is dissipating 90 milliwatts. Chances are your potentiometer can handle this power.

Comment: Label your lower voltage rail "0V" rather than -15V, unless it really is a split-rail supply. What's the ADC-DAC part for, is that just to make the exercise harder?

Comment: @HL-SDK Oh so it wouldn't hurt if I place one? I just want to play it safe...thanks for your comment!

Comment: @pjc50    I think so but I really don't get the point of adding those two not to mention ADC's and DAC's are costly

Comment: Best clarify your requirements then to make sure you need them :) - perhaps the input and output parts are supposed to be separated, with a digital link between?

Comment: @pjc50 Ok I've just learned that  the ADC-> DAC part is optional but I still want to know how it can be done...we were supposed to work in pairs but i can't rely on my groupmate

Comment: If PWM is an option: delta sigma modulator with current sense feedback. Why is no-PWM a requirement?

Comment: @jippie I have no idea what that is but i searched it on wikipedia and saw a diagram that consists of op amp circuits @_@....I think we haven't reached that topic yet. (computer engineering student here)

Edit: We weren't taught that....yet (ARDUINO...?)

Comment: A delta sigma modulator is in essence little more than an opamp/comparator and a low pass filter. Sorry I can't find the simple circuit diagram that I was thinking of right now.

Comment: ADC -> DAC: I would start by finding a cheap available ADC that doesn't have fiddly control requirements, one you can just supply a clock to. Then find a matching DAC. Then design a clock source. It's a significant piece of work. You could just do it with a microcontroller but that feels not in the spirit of the thing.

Comment: @jippie Oh that's ok it looks like i have to read up about those...it's 2am here in my place...i'm gonna call it a day

Comment: @pjc50 i started canvassing earlier this afternoon and found out that the available (and most cheap) one is the adc0808. would a 555 timer be enough?

Comment: 555 would work for the low sample rate you require there, yes.

Comment: @pjc50 i've started reading the adc0808 data sheet and found out that its operating voltage is from 4.5-6v...how do i go about this? do i add a new supply or do i
A.) place a resistor before the adc
B.) place a voltage regulator IC (LM317)
C.) op -amp circuit with <1 gain....

Comment: Resistors are never suitable for reducing power supply voltages. Either add a 5V supply (think carefully about ground!) or add a voltage regulator. Current draw in the digital section will be tiny so a linear regulator might be OK. Do you have +15V,0V,-15V rails or just 30V/0V rails?

Comment: .. I just can't understand the high voltage power supply and low voltage motor, that's just asking for trouble. The whole thing at 5V would make more sense. Maybe it's there to zap the unwary student trying to debug the thing.

Comment: @pjc50 I have a +15, -15 supply since i'll be using my school's dual power supply.
hmmm if its 5v you're talking about maybe i can just use the 7805 voltage regulator?

Oh yeah he says we won't be needing to fabricate this anymore just wiring it to a breadboard would be OK XD

Comment: Controlling voltage across a DC motor is not the same thing as controlling its speed. To actually control the speed you need to go closed-loop with some sort of feedback. No problem hitting a 3v motor with 15v to get it going, but you need to control the current to avoid burning it out.

Comment: @JohnU I'm planning to place an ADC -> DAC after the op amp. but one problem that's gonna arise is that i won't be able to spin my motor in reverse since the DAC would output a positive current...how do I solve this? My prof didn't mention anything about closed or open loop stuff but he did say that a feedback is optional it would maintain the speed of the motor

Comment: And the ADC->DAC would do what exactly?

Comment: I don't know myself but we're required to place it in our design.

Comment: There is no actual speed feedback Nor any form of closed loop... This isn't speed control, this is just voltage control and reliant in not overloading the machine w.r.t. it T-S capability to maintain speed control

Answer (score 1):

As its only a 3V motor I'd limit the speed controller range by adding a resistor above and below the pot RV1. A 10k resistor either side will limit the output swing to +/- 5V and give you finer control over the speed. Increasing these values will reduce the voltage range even further if required.
[image]

By the way - I suspect your professor was looking for a **closed loop type speed control** rather than **the open loop type you have**. Hence the references to ADC, DAC and low pass filters. This would also require a tachometer (usually some form of pulse/frequency device the output of which would require conversion to an analogue signal - DAC) to measure the speed of the motor shaft.

It might be a good idea to clarify from your professor exactly what is required for this project (open loop or closed loop?) before committing to a final design.

Comment: Ooh I updated my schematic by removing the 50 ohm resistor after the push-pull config and then placed 20k resistors on both sides of the bot so that i would have a -3 to +3 voltage drop at my motor


He didn't say anything about open/closed loop control...he just wants an adc -> dac in the circuit.

Comment: @Ephemeral How very curious.There is no reason I can see that you actually need an ADC and DAC in an open loop speed control circuit or even the need for an op amp. The output transistors could be directly controlled from the wiper of the potentiometer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a low-pass filter with a 100Hz cutoff frequency, you'll need to make some changes. The 10uF/16K you show (while completely feasible) will have a -3dB cutoff frequency of 1Hz (quite a bit less, actually, for reasons I will describe).

The source impedance looking into the 10K pot wiper (with your 20K resistors at each end) is not zero, and that will add to the 16K resistor. Ignoring wiper resistance, when the pot is in the center, it will be 12.5K. When the pot is at either end it will be 12K. So we can use 12.25K as an approximation.

Let's pick a standard capacitor value (because resistors come in finer steps). We know it should about 1/100 of what we had before, so let's try something nice and even like 100nF.

$$R = \frac{1}{2 \pi f_c C} = 15.9K\Omega $$

Subtract the 12.25K we get from the pot/resistor divider source impedance, and the resistor should be about 3.6K.  (The cutoff will change a bit with pot rotation, but not enough to worry about- less than 2% each way).